# Roadmanager in osmdroid android

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

Hi I want to create offline map using osmdroid library.
I want to add two point in map and showing road between it.
For that I use this code

```
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager();
ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

myItemizedOverlay.addItem(MyItemizedOverlay.touchpoint, "touch", "touch");
waypoints.add(userlocation);//start point

waypoints.add(MyItemizedOverlay.touchpoint);// end point 
Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
PathOverlay  roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road, getApplicationContext());
mapView.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
```

but when I want to use it I'm getting this error message.

```
RoadManager cannot be resolved
```

I add osmdroid-android-4.2.jar and slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar
And I see [this link](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/tree/master/OpenStreetMapViewer) and I try to import it but I'm giving this error message

```
build path contain duplicate entry src for project
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoadManager is part of OSMBonusPack.

First of all, you should follow [OSMBonusPack HowToInstall](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude) guide.

And then follow [OSMBonusPack tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0).